# Error in building OpenCV

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, image-processing, cmake

I am trying to build OpenCV (with contribe modules and cuda enabled) from scratch. I do this job more than ten times and I used it successfully but this time there is an error I do not recognize it. In the building section with visual studio I see about 100 errors like this one:

***LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '....\lib\Debug\opencv_imgproc330d.lib'***

The steps of my building are:

1- Download OpenCV source files.

2- Download OpenCV_Contrib

3- Copy contrib modules to the source one.

4- Config and generate with CMake GUI.

5- Build with Visual studio 2015

I try it with different OpenCV versions, but there is no difference...

Thanks a lot

System information

OpenCV => 3.0, 3.3, 3.41 tested.

Operating System => Windows 10 64 Bit

Compiler => Visual Studio 2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I setup cuda version 8 and disabled integration with visual studio. Now that is OK.